# Android non-static inner class memory issue

Tags: android, memory-leaks, inner-classes, non-static

I have written the following class inside one of my adapters. The class gets a view from the activity inside its constructor:

```
    private class ContactViewHolder {
       public TextView tvPrimary;
       public TextView tvSecondary;
       public ImageView imageViewCheck;


       public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
           this.tvPrimary = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_primary);
           this.imageViewCheck = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_check);
           v.findViewById(R.id.iv_mm_user);
           this.tvSecondary = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_secondary);
       }
   }
```

Will this lead to a memory leak issue?
It seems it might cause a memory leak, as described in [this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html), regarding a slightly different issue.

So, to sum up, I want to know:

1. Will this cause a memory leak issue?
2. If so, why?

Comment: As long as it is not static, no should be any problem

Comment: you get to know it clearly here https://blogs.oracle.com/olaf/entry/memory_leaks_made_easy

Comment: Your inner class (unless static) will keep your outer class in RAM if someone else than your outer class holds a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you define a instance like this:

```
static ContactViewHolder  holder = new ContactViewHolder(view);
```

It will result in a memory leak.

If you define a non-static instance, it has no memory leak.

The reason of leak is as follows:

No-static inner class will hold a reference of outter class instance, so a static holder will hold a reference of your adapter.
As is known to all, static instance can not be collected by GC, it's a gc root, so your adapter can not be collected until the process is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leaks occures when you dont know/control the lifecycle of the inner class object. Because its not being collected by the GC then the object the holds him doesn't get collected and so on and that causes a memory leak. Basically if your holder only handles with the ui in the simplest way like you wrote then there is no way that he will *"outlive"* the adapter that holds him then it will not cause a memory leak.

If for some reason you are implementing onClick listener inside the Holder which open an AsyncTask for example then you dont control the life-cycle of the object because it opens a new Thread and might be doing some operation while the adapter is no longer on the UI and that will cause a memory leak.

Conclusion:
Be very aware of the lifecycle of your objects and who owns them.